# Get SVN keyword ($Id$) of a file directly from a Perl script

Tags: perl, svn

Are there any Perl methods or modules to get the SVN keyword of a given file without calling the system SVN installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not involve SVN, then the file is just a text file. Whether or not it is version controlled is not a property of the file but is stored in the hidden .svn folder on the same level. That means, if you want to analyze the file without involving SVN, you have to treat it as a plain text file. However, expanded SVN keywords do follow a certain syntax (or SVN itself would be unable to find them after they have been expanded once).
In your case, any file that had the keyword substituted most likely has a line like

```
$Id: ActualIdHere $
```

and if the keyword has not yet been substituded, it will just be `$Id$`. And Perl is very able to extract data from a known syntax. Especially given that you should know what characters can make up an Id (hint: Avoid $ if any possible).

To answer your specific question: A regex like `/^\$Id\: (.*) \$$/` should probably find the Id you are looking for and store it in `$1`. That is of course assuming there is nothing else in that line. But only you can know how and where you have what sort of keywords, so it is up to you to craft the regex or to provide more detailed information, if you struggle to.

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like this, to get the svn id into a perl variable.

```
my ($SVN_ID) = ('$Id: ActualIdHere $' =~ /^\$Id\: (.*) \$$/);
print $SVN_ID;
```

But for SVN you also have to enable keyword substitution in SVN, see [svn documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)

Note: the inserted id is the value at the time the file was last changed. The id may have changed later than that for other files.